# Torch recognizes GPU but not Tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I have a docker container running a Flask app, I am both using tensorflow and pytorch.
In `torch` I can use the GPU but not in Tensorflow.

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.41.03              Driver Version: 530.41.03    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4                        Off| 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   60C    P0               29W /  70W|   1146MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't understand why `nvidia-smi` show a cuda version but `nvcc` doesn't work, and I can't install the cuda toolkit using `apt` in the `python:3.9-slim` docker image.

`nvcc --version` output:

```
bash: nvcc: command not found
```

`import tensorflow` output:

```
2023-07-01 21:12:51.765379: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-07-01 21:12:51.814111: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-07-01 21:12:51.814886: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-07-01 21:12:53.284879: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

`torch` output:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>>
```

`Dockerfile`

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD gunicorn 'main:app' --bind=0.0.0.0:80 --timeout=36000000 --workers=1 --threads=8
```

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Can you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) page of TensorFlow states that `NVIDIA® GPU drivers version 450.80.02 or higher`, `CUDA® Toolkit 11.8` and `cuDNN SDK 8.6.0` are required. Installation of `TensorRT` is optional but improves latency and throughput for inference.
Your image doesn't contain anything of that because you don't execute any of the steps mentioned on the TensorFlow installation page in your `Dockerfile`. And you haven't posted your `requirements.txt`.

Maybe consider to use a [TensorFlow (Dockerhub)](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/)/[TensorFlow (NVIDIA)](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow) docker image directly.

Comment: `
pandas==1.5.3
pyannote.audio @ https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip
pyannote.core==5.0.0
pyannote.database==5.0.1
pyannote.metrics==3.2.1
pyannote.pipeline==2.3
pytorch-lightning==2.0.3
pytorch-metric-learning==2.1.2
scikit-learn==1.2.2
scipy==1.10.1
spleeter==2.3.2
tensorboard==2.12.3
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.0
tensorboardX==2.6
tensorflow==2.12.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.32.0
torch==2.0.1
torch-audiomentations==0.11.0
torch-pitch-shift==1.2.4
torchaudio==2.0.2
torchmetrics==0.11.4
`